# Include template on ng-click in angulajs

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-include

I have created discussion forum application in angularjs. Once the user clicked the reply button on the post, I want to show the editor which is in the separate html file. How can I include that template on clicking the ng-click under that specific post.

Comment: Show what you have tried. An example also have anchor the question with some specifics

Comment: Editor.html
<textarea class="Editor"></textarea>
Post.html
<div data-ng-repeat="t in threadInfo" id="{{t.ID}}" style="margin: 0px; background-color: #fafafa; border: solid 1px #ccc; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<label style="color: #003c6b; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;" data-ng-bind="t.Title"></label>
<a class="reply" style="width: 50px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;" href="" data-ng-click="InsertEditor()">Reply</a>
<div class="reply"></div>
</div>
On ng-click, I want to insert the editor.html file under specific post

Comment: I meant, by editing the question - not in comments

Answer (score 1):

How about a combination of `ng-include` with `ng-if`?

If you want to inject a template based on a certain condition, you can do it like this:

`<div ng-include="'template.html'" ng-if="yourCondition"> </div>`

where `template.html` is your filename and `yourCondition` should be an boolean expression.

Here is  a plnkr to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/m50nKigoOWYwuczBIQdQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above we can use combination of ng-if and ng-include to achieve require functionality  :

```
<html ng-app="includeApp">
<head>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="AppController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <button ng-click="injectReply()">Include Reply</button>
<div ng-include="'reply.html'" ng-if="isReplyIncluded"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now code containing AppController.js :

```
angular.module('includeApp',[])
  .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
   $scope.isReplyIncluded=false;
    $scope.injectReply= function (){
   //add reply.html by making this variable true
     $scope.isReplyIncluded=true;
    }
  }]);
```

Reply.html

```
<div>
You can add your editor html content here
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Keshav, Thanks for your reply. The page will contain n number of posts.I have to insert the editor exactly under the post where the reply button is clicked. Hope my question in clear.